# How to fix "File" *.service "configures an IP firewall (IPAddressDeny=any), but the local system does not support BPF/cgroup based firewalling"?

Tags: linux, systemd, linux-kernel, firewall

Booting from a kernel which I recompiled with a custom `.config`, I got the the following kmsg(ie. `dmesg`) message:

```
systemd[1]: File /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service:35 configures an IP firewall (IPAddressDeny=any), but the local system does not support BPF/cgroup based firewalling.
systemd[1]: Proceeding WITHOUT firewalling in effect! (This warning is only shown for the first loaded unit using IP firewalling.)
```

What kernel `.config` options do I need to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First enable `CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y`

```
┌── Enable bpf() system call ─────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                             │
│ CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL:                                         │
│                                                             │
│ Enable the bpf() system call that allows to manipulate eBPF │
│ programs and maps via file descriptors.                     │
│                                                             │
│ Symbol: BPF_SYSCALL [=y]                                    │
│ Type  : bool                                                │
│ Prompt: Enable bpf() system call                            │
│   Location:                                                 │
│     -> General setup                                        │
│   Defined at init/Kconfig:1414                              │
│   Selects: ANON_INODES [=y] && BPF [=y] && IRQ_WORK [=y]    │
│   Selected by [n]:                                          │
│   - AF_KCM [=n] && NET [=y] && INET [=y]                    │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

^ that allows you to then also enable `CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF=y`:

```
┌── Support for eBPF programs attached to cgroups ─────────────────┐
│                                                                  │
│ CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF:                                               │
│                                                                  │
│ Allow attaching eBPF programs to a cgroup using the bpf(2)       │
│ syscall command BPF_PROG_ATTACH.                                 │
│                                                                  │
│ In which context these programs are accessed depends on the type │
│ of attachment. For instance, programs that are attached using    │
│ BPF_CGROUP_INET_INGRESS will be executed on the ingress path of  │
│ inet sockets.                                                    │
│                                                                  │
│ Symbol: CGROUP_BPF [=y]                                          │
│ Type  : bool                                                     │
│ Prompt: Support for eBPF programs attached to cgroups            │
│   Location:                                                      │
│     -> General setup                                             │
│       -> Control Group support (CGROUPS [=y])                    │
│   Defined at init/Kconfig:845                                    │
│   Depends on: CGROUPS [=y] && BPF_SYSCALL [=y]                   │
│   Selects: SOCK_CGROUP_DATA [=y]                                 │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

That's all that's necessary for those `systemd` messages to go away.

When you select the above, this is what happens in `.config`:
Before:

```
# CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL is not set
```

After:

```
CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y
# CONFIG_XDP_SOCKETS is not set
# CONFIG_BPF_STREAM_PARSER is not set
CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF_EVENTS=y
```

Two more options become available: `CONFIG_XDP_SOCKETS` and `CONFIG_BPF_STREAM_PARSER` but it's not necessary to enable them. But if you're wondering what they are about:

```
┌── XDP sockets ────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                       │
│ CONFIG_XDP_SOCKETS:                                   │
│                                                       │
│ XDP sockets allows a channel between XDP programs and │
│ userspace applications.                               │
│                                                       │
│ Symbol: XDP_SOCKETS [=n]                              │
│ Type  : bool                                          │
│ Prompt: XDP sockets                                   │
│   Location:                                           │
│     -> Networking support (NET [=y])                  │
│       -> Networking options                           │
│   Defined at net/xdp/Kconfig:1                        │
│   Depends on: NET [=y] && BPF_SYSCALL [=y]            │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌── enable BPF STREAM_PARSER ───────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                       │
│ CONFIG_BPF_STREAM_PARSER:                                             │
│                                                                       │
│ Enabling this allows a stream parser to be used with                  │
│ BPF_MAP_TYPE_SOCKMAP.                                                 │
│                                                                       │
│ BPF_MAP_TYPE_SOCKMAP provides a map type to use with network sockets. │
│ It can be used to enforce socket policy, implement socket redirects,  │
│ etc.                                                                  │
│                                                                       │
│ Symbol: BPF_STREAM_PARSER [=n]                                        │
│ Type  : bool                                                          │
│ Prompt: enable BPF STREAM_PARSER                                      │
│   Location:                                                           │
│     -> Networking support (NET [=y])                                  │
│       -> Networking options                                           │
│   Defined at net/Kconfig:301                                          │
│   Depends on: NET [=y] && BPF_SYSCALL [=y]                            │
│   Selects: STREAM_PARSER [=m]                                         │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

If wondering why `CONFIG_BPF_EVENTS=y`:

```
┌── Search Results ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                                                                                         │
│ Symbol: BPF_EVENTS [=y]                                                                                                                 │
│ Type  : bool                                                                                                                            │
│   Defined at kernel/trace/Kconfig:476                                                                                                   │
│   Depends on: TRACING_SUPPORT [=y] && FTRACE [=y] && BPF_SYSCALL [=y] && (KPROBE_EVENTS [=n] || UPROBE_EVENTS [=y]) && PERF_EVENTS [=y] │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Kernel tested 4.18.5 on a Fedora 28 AppVM inside Qubes OS 4.0

Comment: you can self-accept answers too.

Comment: @intelfx Sweet! ("You can accept your own answer in 2 days")

Answer (score 1):

If all the above options are already set, try adding systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1 to your kernel command line.

This enables cgroups v2, which was the missing piece (at least for my setup) to enable IP firewalling in BPF and get rid of the error in dmesg logs.