# How can I restrict the network access of a systemd service?

Tags: systemd, iptables, cgroups

I have a custom systemd service which I want to restrict to the local interface. On [ctrl.blog systemd application firewalls examples](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/systemd-application-firewall.html) I found that it should be possible to achieve this using only the service file. To make sure its working, I first tried to deny any network access:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyService
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/myservice/
User=msu
Group=msu

Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/opt/myservice/myservice

IPAddressDeny=any # should block networking entirely

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However the service is still working, so the line `IPAddressDeny=any` seems to have no effect. I then tried to apply an `iptables` rule to the `cgroup` created by systemd. Again, I tested by applying a rule that should deny all networking:

```
iptables -A INPUT  -m cgroup --path "/system.slice/myservice.service" -j REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --path "/system.slice/myservice.service" -j REJECT
```

But the service is still running and now I am out of ideas how to enforce network filters to my systemd service.

Comment: Could it be that your kernel has no support for cgroups firewalling? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467362/how-to-fix-file-service-configures-an-ip-firewall-ipaddressdeny-any-but

Comment: When I created a custom cgroup using `mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/jail` and added a process by `echo $PID > /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/jail/tasks`, the `iptables`-method worked. Is there an easy way to check for kernel support, though?

Comment: You could try setting `PrivateNetwork=true` instead?

Comment: This is preventing network access, but now I can not even connect to the service on localhost.